# How to force IntelliJ completion to overwrite by default using the mous

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I know that you can change the behaviour with Keymap and swap the *tab* and *enter* key.

But that won't work when selecting with the mouse on the completion list.

How can you make completion selection with the mouse overwrite instead of inserting in IntelliJ IDEA?

Similar to
[Eclipse Completion Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn6kM.png)

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.